# tooltip inside popover stays after popover is closed - ZeroClipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to add buttons to popover that will allow user to copy content.
I managed to build prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/VUZhL/890/
but I have weird error when using tipsy inside popover:

[image]

After clicking on `Click for action` button I get popover with 2 buttons, they both have tooltips, sometimes after clicking on button tooltip stays visible.

My code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').tipsy({
        title: 'data-tipsy-title',
        gravity: function () {
            return this.getAttribute('data-tipsy-gravity') || 'n';
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#example, .tip', function (event) {
        $(this).tipsy("hide");
    });
    $('#example').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        title: '',
        html: true,
        template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content no-padding"></div></div>',
        content: '<div class="btn-group">' +
            '<button type="button" title="link" class="btn btn-default tip number"><span class="fa fa-link"></span></button>' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default tip" title="something else"><span class="fa fa-copy"></span></button>' +
            '</div>'
    });

    $('#example').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        //tipsy
        $('.tip').tipsy({
            gravity: 's'
        });
        //zero clipboard
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard($(".tip"));
        clip.on("copy", function (event) {
            var clipboard = event.clipboardData;
            var data = "";
            if ($(event.target).hasClass("number")) {
                data = "1st button"+new Date()
            } else {
                data = "second";
            }
            clipboard.setData("text/plain", data);
            ZeroClipboard.deactivate();
        });
    })

    //zero clipboard
    ZeroClipboard.config({
        hoverClass: "hover"
    });
});
```

My questions:
1. How can this be fixed?
2. Is ZeroClipboard initialized in right place? I can't do that before, because buttons are added when popover is shown for first time.

Comment: Why not use Bootstrap's built-in Tooltip widget instead of Tipsy?

Comment: @cvrebert - I'm using tipsy in all my projects, but I can switch to bootstrap 3 tooltips if that will solve the problem. I'll let You know if that helped

Comment: @cvrebert will I be able to use popover and tooltip on same element (`Click for action` button)?

Comment: @cvrebert - Yes, we can use popover and tooltip on same element - http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/VUZhL/903/

Comment: @cvrebert - I have almost working solution, all I need is to get this working nice in IE10 and IE11